# Removing parentheses, text proceeding comma, and the comma in a string using string

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a string that contains a persons name and city. It's formatted like this:

```
mock <- "Joe Smith (Cleveland, OH)"
```

I simply want the state abbreviation remaining, so it in this case, the only remaining string would be "OH"

I can get rid of the the parentheses and comma

```
[(.*?),]
```

Which gives me:

```
"Joe Smith Cleveland OH"
```

But I can't figure out how to combine all of it. For the record, all of the records will look like that, where it ends with ", two letter capital state abbreviation" (ex: ", OH", ", KY", ", MD" etc...)

Comment: https://ideone.com/LEidIv, either `sub("\\(\\w+,\\s*(\\w+)\\)$","\\1",mock)` or a more generic `sub("\\([^,)]+,\\s*([^)]*)\\)$","\\1",mock)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
mock <- "Joe Smith (Cleveland, OH)"
sub(".+,\\s*([A-Z]{2})\\)$","\\1",mock)
## => [1] "OH"
## With stringr:
str_extract(mock, "[A-Z]{2}(?=\\)$)")
```

See [this R demo](https://ideone.com/P7PjFw)

**Details**

- `.+,\\s*([A-Z]{2})\\)$` - matches any 1+ chars as many as possible, then `,`, 0+ whitespaces, and then captures 2 uppercase ASCII letters into Group 1 (referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern) and then matches `)` at the end of string
- `[A-Z]{2}(?=\)$)` - matches 2 uppercase ASCII letters if followed with the `)` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

How about this.  If they are all formatted the same, then this should work.

```
mock <- "Joe Smith (Cleveland, OH)"
substr(mock, (nchar(mock) - 2), (nchar(mock) - 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the general case is that the state is in the second and third last characters then match everything, `.*`, and then a capture group of two characters `(..)` and then another character `.` and replace that with the capture group:

```
sub(".*(..).", "\\1", mock)
## [1] "OH"
```